# Exploiting buffer overflow

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow

When I download a copy of a vulnerable program and try to exploit it by buffer overflow (any internal function calling as a payload), it works.
However, when I made a same type of vulnerable program in C I am not able to exploit it and I have no idea what's going wrong. Checking on `gdb` I figure out that I am able to overwrite the return address on the stack but still getting a segmentation fault and my desired address is not executed.

The vulnerable program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

input()
{
    char a[4];

    gets(a);
    puts(a);
}

main()
{
    input();
    printf("\nthis will execute after returning from the function\n");
}


over()
{
    printf("this can only be executed by the hacker");
}
```

I want to execute the function `over()` and I used the payload

```
printf "aaaaaaaa\xb3\x84\x04\x08" | ./my
```

Comment: Your compiler is putting in tricks to try and make buffer overflows harder. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340259/how-to-turn-off-gcc-compiler-optimization-to-enable-buffer-overflow

Comment: i have disabled aslr and also used the switch -mprefrred-stack-boundary=2 and even the vulnerable program which seems to work i used the same switch

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is that it ***isn't*** vulnerable to a buffer overflow more than likely due to the compiler (are you using gcc?) replacing`gets` with`fgets`

If you strace the above compiled code (with malicious input) you should see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you've disabled ASLR (and checked that it's really disabled), you may be running into a [canary](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20502/120672).  Disable it using the `-fno-stack-protector` flag:

```
gcc my.c -o my -fno-stack-protector
```