# how to circumvent ASLR without pointer leaks

Tags: exploit, aslr, exploit-development

is there way to circumvent ASLR without pointer leaks, I mean i read many exploit development course Syllabus and many of them talk about bypass ASLR without pointer leaks, Does anyone can explain to me how it is.

i read
[How "leaking pointers" to bypass DEP/ASLR works](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22989/how-leaking-pointers-to-bypass-dep-aslr-works)
[How do ASLR and DEP work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18556/how-do-aslr-and-dep-work)

Comment: Do you have references to these courses?

Comment: @NeilSmithline http://ptrace-security.com/training/courses/advanced-software-exploitation/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Shane it's not really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

There are ways, but they depend on the context of exploitation. No one size fits all I'm afraid. Some example techniques of bypassing ASLR;
- Partial address overwrite
- Brute force
- Using non-ASLR libraries.
- Non-PIE binaries
- Forcing a non-ASLR library to trigger
- Heap spraying

I'm sure there are more techniques I missed. But life is a lot easier if you can get a memory leak.