# What is binary executable randomization?

Tags: penetration-test, attacks, vulnerability

I am trying to get more information about `binary executable randomization` that is used for increasing uncertainty for attacker toward software vulnerability. I've been searching on Google but still couldn't find a clear explanation. Can someone provide an explanation of a link that can help me understand this?

Comment: what resources did you use?

Comment: Did you by any chance read this paper: http://bitblaze.cs.berkeley.edu/papers/CCFIR-oakland-CR.pdf ? It seems to have the same title as your question

Comment: You might want to look at this thread http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18556/how-do-aslr-and-dep-work.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you're looking for the term [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). The techniques mentioned in the comments are for completely preventing things like [ROP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return-oriented_programming) gadgets. ASLR will jumble the layout of the program in memory, so an attacker cant easily say "the return address i need to overwrite to redirect the control flow of the program is at offset X past the buffer i overflowed"

Comment: I had the same idea but when I searched the term that @Alli mentioned, I realised that there were papers so I add then

Comment: Yeah me too. But i checked his other questions and he asked the difference between a vpn and ipsec.